# Running bash file on Heroku

Tags: bash, shell, heroku

I'm trying to start my Discord bot using a bash file on Heroku, so the bot wil automaticly restart when it gets an error.

My worker on Heroku is: `chmod a+x run.sh`

The run.sh file:

```
#!/bin/sh
function main(){
node .
echo "The bot is crashed, restarting now..."
main
}
main
```

Edit: I changed the worker to `bash run.sh` and limited the run.sh file to:

```
#!/bin/bash
node index.js
echo "The bot is online."
```

Now I'm getting this response: `Error: Cannot find module '/app/index.js`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to (and shouldn't) write your own startup script with Heroku. That's what the [`Procfile`](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/procfile#procfile-format) is for. Something like this should do it:

```
worker: node index.js
```

That defines a `worker` process type that will run `node index.js`. Then, as long as you have a `worker` dyno running, your script should run.

Comment: I know this, but I want to use a bash file which automaticly starts the bot again if there's an error, to make sure it's always running, even if a small error occures.

Comment: Heroku [automatically restarts crashed dynos, too](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#dyno-crash-restart-policy). If your dynos are crashing regularly enough that this is insufficient (e.g. that the cool-off period affects your running app) you need to solve the crashing problem. Just restarting all the time isn't the right solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your header to `/bin/bash`. `function` is not POSIX. You can also just omit `function` if you won't be using other bash features.

Also I notice that you're calling main from main and that would cause repeated calls. Even if that's intended it would still be better to use a loop. Bash is not tail call optimzation aware.

Comment: I'm still getting this error in the logs: Process exited with status 0

Comment: That sounds to be success. If you have issues with node or heroku itself, try asking a different question specific to it in SuperUser or Server Fault. StackOverflow is only for the scripting.

Comment: The script looks to me besides thr possibility that its lines end with CRLF.